# How to reset the div tag in jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a drop down box in my html page where I need to reset the drop down list back to its original state. My code snippet is as follows:

```
<div id="countries" >
 <!---------------I select a particular module----------------->
     <select id="modules" onchange = "getRole()"> <!--Function getRole() called here-->
                <option>---Select---</option>
                <option value="1">Module1</option>
                <option value="2">Module2</option>
                <option value="3">Module3</option>
                <option value="4">Module4</option>
        </select>
  <!-Based on the modules some processing is done and countries are displayed->
     <select multiple="multiple" id="country" name="country[]">

            <option value="1">India</option>
            <option value="2">USA</option>
            <option value="3">Russia</option>

       </select> 
</div>
```

I need reset the drop down menu after doing some processing

In other words I need to get back my original state after doing all the processing using my drop down.

I m using .clone() but that dosen't seem to be working.

```
function getRole() {
    //CLone the id 'countries'
    var cloneobj = $('#countries').clone();

    //Some processing here
    ....

    //After processing get back the original state
    $('#countries').replaceWith(cloneObj);
}
```

The problem here is clone is creating duplicate id's and hence dosent seem to be the right solution. Can anyone help. Please

Comment: BTW... you should use `$('#countries').clone();` with an `#` id reference and a small `c` in `Clone()`

Answer (score 1):

First, provide `#` for id

```
var cloneobj = $('#countries').clone();
```

and try

```
$('#countries').replaceWith(cloneObj);
```

Javascript is case sensitive for functions !!!

**`clone()` is different than `Clone()`**.

**UPDATE 2**

I caught you: you miss `</select>` tag and comments issue

```
<div id="countries" >
 <!---------------I select a particular module----------------->
     <select id="modules" onchange = "getRole()"> <!--Function getRole() called here-->
                <option>---Select---</option>
                <option value="1">Module1</option>
                <option value="2">Module2</option>
                <option value="3">Module3</option>
                <option value="4">Module4</option>

     </select> <!-- Here you forgot -->

  <!--Based on the modules some processing is done and countries are displayed !. You forgot one `-` -->
     <select multiple="multiple" id="country" name="country[]">

            <option value="1">India</option>
            <option value="2">USA</option>
            <option value="3">Russia</option>

       </select> 
</div>
```

**UPDATE 3**

See my example using jquery event: http://jsfiddle.net/6WLVC/

Still, I don't know why `getRole()` doesn't work yet using `onchange` event in `select` tag.

Seems that jQuery functions work only in `$(function(){ ... });` initialization.

Comment: Sorry for those syntax errors.. I m not getting solution right even after the right syntax

Comment: @Neal: Read **UPDATE 2** from my answer.

Comment: A copying error - I have proper syntax in my code. But I m still not getting

Comment: Please try to copy CORRECTLY, in this case we can't help if you copied incorrectly

Comment: You are close I don need a duplicate copy of it I need to replace it. So result should be oly one copy. And the function is working but I am just not getting the right solution what I want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16875/discussion-between-neal-and-snake-eyes)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `clone()`(**case sensitive**), **use the id hash** `#`, and use the **correct object** to do the replace. (You save the cloned object in `cloneobj`and replace using `cloneObj` which is undefined (**case sensitive**!)

clone the options and replace like this:

```
function getRole() {
    //Clone the id 'countries'
    var clonedObj = $('#countries').clone();

    //Some processing here
    ....

    //After processing get back the original state
    $('countries').replaceWith(clonedObj);
}
```

Comment: I need the entire DOM structure as it is before before doing any changes. I m not getting tat

Comment: Put `$('#countries').html(clonedOptions);`

Comment: I modified my example to just clone the entire structure. The point is, case sensitivity and using correct selectors ;)